# Comparing values of two columns and filtering the data in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataset of 3 columns product, region and sales. Suppose there are 2 products(A, B) and 2 regions(1, 2)(Region is of numeric dtype). What I am doing is this to filter the data according to a particular product and a particular region :

```
data[(data['Product'] == 'A') & (data['Region'] == 1)]
```

Above code is giving the filtered data. But later on I have done categorical encoding on product w.r.t sales so that I can train the model as product will become numeric dtype from categorical encoding. I have done categorical encoding because I have 2000 products in the dataset.
So when I am trying this after encoding 'Product' column:

```
data[(data['Product'] == 1.231) & (data['Region'] == 1)]
```

It gives empty dataframe, no rows in it.
What could be the reason behind it? And I want to filter the data after encoding but it is not giving any data.

Comment: Maybe `data['Product'].cat.codes.eq(1231)`?

Comment: Can you please explain the code @QuangHoang? I am really not able to understand it. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: When you convert a series to categorical, `.cat.codes` gives you the *numeric* values of the series and `.eq(val)` is almost the same as `== val`. Also, the `codes` for categorical data are always integers.

Comment: But my data is already converted to numeric values by categorical encoding. So I tried this : data[data['Product'].eq(123)]          
But it is still giving empty data.

Comment: can u show a sample of your data set?

Comment: `Categorical encoding` is not `int`. So when you compare `df['Product']` to an `int` value, you would get all `False`. similar to compare `'1'==1` would give you `False`, correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct @Quang. But my product column is of float dtype. So, can't  i compare it this some float value?

Comment: How do you know it's float type? you can try print `df['Product'].unique()` to see what the values are.

Comment: I tried data.dtypes and it gives the data types of all the columns present in the dataset.